# Eclipse importing files

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm a student and I got java files which I should work with. 
I tried to import throw importing "File system".
My problem is with this line: "**package bgu.spl.a2;**".
How can I fix it without changing the files structure? [image]

Comment: it should be main.java.package bgu.spl.a2

Comment: In _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, in the tab _Source_ select `a2/src`, click _Edit..._ and replace `src` with `src/main/java`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a standard eclipse java project. In this project, java packages are stored in the folder `src`.

But the code is provided as a *maven* project following the [Maven Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) where the java sources are in `src/main/java`.

Most likely there was a file called `pom.xml` along with the source file.

You have two options:

1. recreate the project as *Maven project*

   - remove the project from the workspace.
   - open the *import* dialog
   - select *maven -> existing maven project*
   - navigate to the folder containing the `pom.xml`

or

2. change the "source folders"
   in the project explorer:

   - right click on `src`
   - select *remove from build path*
   - navigate to src/main/java
   - right click on `java`
   - select *add to build path*